# What does a pointer *(x+i) do?

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I believe I roughly understood what pointers do, but I don't get what a pointer *(x+i) does.
So for example *(x+1).
Does it point to x and increase it's value by 1 or what?

Also I found this example:
*(x+1) = 5

What does that do?

Thanks for your replies!

Comment: it increments the pointer by 1 and deferences the pointer

Comment: It's important to understand that `*(x+1)` does _not_ change the value of the pointer `x`.  It only offsets that one memory access.

Comment: What did your book tell you?

Comment: `What the hell does that do?`....well, probably you're gonna need a little more patience....

Comment: @user3528438: Nonsense! The pointer iss not modified!

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Patience will not help. Reading the intro chapter about pointers otoh will.

Comment: @Olaf isn't that exactly what I asked in the very previous comment, sir? :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh: To me: yes, sir. But judging from the question I wanted to make sure OP **reads** the book, not just sits and listens what it might _tell_ :-)

Comment: @Olaf Absolutely, no doubts. That __is__ the first thing to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*(x+1)` is exactly the same as the clearer `x[1]`. Regard this as the value of the second element of the *array* whose first element is at the address `x`.

So `*(x+1) = 5;` is the same as `x[1] = 5;`, which is assigning the value `5` to the element of the array `x` at position `1`.

Note that it (and the way you have it - `*(x+1)`) is *only* defined if `x` is the address of an element of an array with at least 1 element after it. Pointer arithmetic is only valid within arrays. Otherwise the behaviour is *undefined* and the compiler might leap up and eat your cat.

Comment: No, not Snuggles!  The compiler can't have her!

Comment: @JohnBollinger: You can save her quite simple: never invoke UB!